# Manually switching views in UIPageViewController causes exception

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UIPageViewController that displays two UIViewControllers and allows the user to swipe between the two. I implemented a button that allows the user to manually switch between the two. The code to execute this is as follows:

```
[self setViewControllers:@[[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PlayersViewController"]] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:^(BOOL completion){}];
```

Unfortunately, every time I press the button, I get an exception that says:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'

I call the method from my custom class that extends the UIPageViewControllerDelegate.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**Edit:

Here are relevant portions of my custom class:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.dataSource = self;
    gvc = [[GamesViewController alloc] init];
    pvc = [[PlayersViewController alloc] init];
    [self setViewControllers:@[[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GamesViewController"]] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
}

- (void) slidepage
{
    [self setViewControllers:@[[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PlayersViewController"]] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:NO completion:^(BOOL completion){NSLog(@"hihi");}];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[GamesViewController class]])
        return nil;

    return [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GamesViewController"];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[PlayersViewController class]])
        return nil;

    return [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PlayersViewController"];
}
```

Comment: Can you at least post your custom class's code?

Comment: How is the `storyboard` property declared?

Comment: It is not explicitly declared in my code. Isn't it a property inherited from UIViewController? The declaration in the documentation is @property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UIStoryboard *storyboard

Comment: Yes, you're right. Documentation says the property is nil if the view controller is not loaded from a storyboard. So the next question is, how do you instantiate this view controller?

Comment: [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];

Comment: Very strange, since this contradicts what the documentation says. Can you confirm that the `storyboard` property of your "PageViewController" is in fact nil right after instantiating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that

```
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PlayersViewController"]
```

returns `nil`. This would mean that either `self.storyboard` is `nil` or the storyboard can't find a view controller for the given identifier.

Comment: After debugging and looking through the properties of my class, I found that storyboard was nil. Do you have any suggestions to fix this?